# colon/semicolon in "they are more than just places to shop: they are also where people socialize"

Tags: punctuation

Does either a colon or a semicolon work? Does the use of the punctuation affect the relationship between the two clauses?

> Physical stores are more than just places to shop: they are also where
> people socialize.

> Physical stores are more than just places to shop; they are also where
> people socialize.

Comment: Semicolon - yes. Colon - no. See [this](https://wmich.edu/writing/punctuation/colon#:~:text=The%20colon%20(%20%3A%20)%20and%20semicolon,should%20not%20be%20used%20interchangeably.).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use a semicolon to connect two related but independent clauses:

> Physical stores are more than just places to shop; they are also where people socialize.

Technically, you can use a colon to separate two independent clauses when the second clarifies the first. So according to the rules, you could use a colon. But it's seldom used that way in practice.

Why not use a period and make it two sentences?

> Physical stores are more than just places to shop. They are also where people socialize.

Comment: Thank you very much for your answer. You mentioned **clarify**. What if I'm **explaining** the first sentence? In this case, can I use a colon? Physical  stores are also where people socialize: at Starbucks, people chat with their friends while enjoying their drinks.